# Plot gradient of a function which is a matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I would like to plot the gradient of the following function in [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB).

```
g(x,y) = [(x^2)-1; -y]
```

My code is:

```
x = linspace(-3,3);
y = linspace(-3,3);
[xx, yy] = meshgrid(x,y);
z = [xx.^2-1;-yy];
[dx,dy] = gradient(z,.3,.3);
contour(x,y,z)
hold on 
quiver(x,y,dx,dy)
```

But I'm just getting this error:

```
The size of Y must match the size of Z or the number of rows
of Z.
```

I've no idea how I could make the size of both match. `y` is a 1x100 matrix and `z` a 200x100. To match them I would need `y` to be a 1x200 or `z` to be 100x100, but would I be able to plot it then?

Comment: The problem is in your definition of the array `z` - what is it that you want to accomplish? Plot `surf(z)` to see what `z` looks like; is that what you intended?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
z = [xx.^2-1;-yy];
```

try each component separately:

```
z1 = [xx.^2-1];
z2 = [-yy];
[dx,dy] = gradient(z1,.3,.3);
contour(x,y,z1)
%etc.
```

Use `hold on` again if you really want them in the same plot.